# accepts_nested_attributes_for whith json PUT (update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have seen many examples of using accepts_nested_attributes_for but only a few of them for json POST/PUT and none of them helped me :/

My application will be used to create forms.

So, a form has many form_rows and a form_row can have many choices (in case it is a select of radio).
So, I have my form model like this :

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :form_rows
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :form_rows
end
```

and my controller looks like this :

```
def update
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    @form.update_attributes!(params[:form])
end
```

Here is the json I am trying to send

```
{
  "name": "form test 4",
  "form_rows_attributes": [
    {
      "domtype": "Input",
      "label": "Super row new"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my scenario, the form creation only takes a name, it is after that that the user add the form_rows.

When I do that, the name is correctly updated but the form_rows are not created at all. There is no error in my console, just the UPDATE for the form.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON needs one more level of nesting so the `params[:form]` call will actually find the params:

```
{ 
  "form": {
    "name": "form test 4",
    "form_rows_attributes": [
      {
        "domtype": "Input",
        "label": "Super row new"
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but only the name is updated. The form_rows are not added :/

Comment: Oups sorry, it works, I was doing it wrong. However, I still have a problem. My form_row can have many choices but a json like that { 
  "form": {
    "name": "form test 4",
    "form_rows_attributes": [
      {
        "domtype": "Input",
        "label": "Super row new",
        "choices" : [
          {
            "name":"choice 1",
            "value": "value1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  } 
}
does not work :/ I have an error : 
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in FormsController#update
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: choices

Comment: @Tagazok do you have something like `attr_accessible :choices` inside the `FormRow` model? You will also need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices` inside your `FormRow` model.

Comment: @Tagazok also, the JSON will need the key `choices_attributes` rather than `choices`. This pattern repeats every time you accept nested attributes for a related model.